# how to Validate a XML file with XSD through xmllint

Tags: xml, linux, xsd, xmllint

i have to validate my xml file with a given XSD file. Figured the easiest way to do so would be xmllint, but i can't get it to work. Can anyone tell me the exact command?

I tried:

```
     xmllint --valid myxsd.xsd myxml.xml
```

What am i doing wrong? This only outputs the 2 files in the command line

edit: have to do it in console, because it will be needed in a build process

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Figured it out, had to use `--schema` instead of `--validate`.

```
xmllint --schema yourxsd.xsd yourxml.xml --noout
```

The `--noout` makes sure your code in XSD and XML doesn't show. With this option you will only see the Validation Errors.

Comment: I tried it and faced this limitation `Internal error: xmlSchemaVDocWalk, there is at least one entity reference in the node-tree currently being validated. Processing of entities with this XML Schema processor is not supported (yet). Please substitute entities before validation.`, so it does not support entities even though they are correctly defined like `<!DOCTYPE root [<!ENTITY nbsp  "&#160;">]>`.

Comment: `apt search xmllint` finds `libxml2-utils`, so `sudo apt install libxml2-utils`

Comment: Thanks. I tried the `--dtdvalid` option, that didn't work.