# Validate XML with XSD in AWS lambda (Typescript / Javascript)

Tags: typescript, xml, npm, aws-lambda, xsd-validation

I am trying to find a library that can be used to validate an XML against a XSD schema file. Since the project is written in Typescript I searched for a JS / TS lib. I found only libraries like this one here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xsd-schema-validator

I am not sure if I want to use libraries like this in my production environment. The production scenario needs to handle a lot of request where this functionality (validating XML against XSD) will be triggered a lot of times. Coming from Java I am used to established libraries like the onse from apache or language build in functionality.

The project is a serverless AWS project, so I want to use AWS lambdas to achieve this. I am aware that I could write a JAVA lambda which would do the job. In this case I would have to work myself around the cold start problem with tools like snapstart. But for now I would like to know how TS / JS projects handle XSD validations. Is it legit to use libraries like the one mentioned above? Did I just not search properly and missed a fitting lib?

Best regards
Aleks

My expectation would be sharing experience from other projects that had similar problems.

Comment: What about using Powershell in window : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822907/how-do-i-use-powershell-to-validate-xml-files-against-an-xsd?force_isolation=true

Comment: AWS lambdas do not have windows based OS underneath rather than linux based. And I do not understand how this should help me.
There is a similar approach to use xmllint on console level to validate the xml, this is actually one of my options I consider. 
I just want to know if some others had experience with TS / JS projects with XML / XSD and what they used.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that you can use from OS.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809088/how-to-validate-a-xml-file-with-xsd-through-xmllint?force_isolation=true.  Also this : https://www.linuxask.com/questions/how-to-validate-the-format-of-a-xml-file-in-linux?force_isolation=true